# Not getting location coordinates unless location has changed

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

Here is what I need to do. I need to launch my application and on the click of a button, I need to display the current coordinates, that is latitude and longitude. I followed [**this**](http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/find-current-location-in-android-gps.html) tutorial and used the following code for my purpose:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final TextView latValueLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latLabel);
        final TextView lonValueLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lonLabel);
        Button setButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set_button);
        setButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                latValueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                lonValueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

(Copy pasted only a part of the code, please ignore any unclosed brackets or anything like that.)

It continuously gets the latitude longitude as location changes and stores it to two `double` variables `latitude` and `longitude` and when the `setButton` is clicked, it displays the last stored lat-lon value. That would be the user's current location. Now the issue is, I launched the app and while still staying on the exact location from which the app is launched, I clicked the Set Button. But at that time the location is not changed, so the latitude and longitude are displayed as zero, which is the default value of the double variables. I need to take a walk around with the device so that the location is changed before I can get my actual coordinates. How can I get the lat-lon as soon as the app is launched?

Comment: Use `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(... )` to initialize the longitude and latitude values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getLastKnownLocation(...)` to initialise the longitude and latitude values like this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Comment: If I use this, I don't need to use LocationListener at all right?

Comment: Yes, but this just returns the last known location. To get location updates you still need to use the `LocationListener`. `getLastKnownLocation()` will as the name implies just to return the last known location. If the user had disabled GPS for a while the last known location might be completely wrong, but there is nothing you can do about that and as such I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Well, when I tried moving around with the device just by using the `getLastKnownlocation()`, it never updated the current location, however far I go, I still had the GPS on, while the location listener updated it correctly. So `getLastKnownLocation()` never requests for a new location?

Comment: You should only use `getLastKnownLocation()` to initialise the longitude and latitude values at the start of your app. The values returned by `getLastKnownLocation()` are not updated instantly when new location data is available. As far as I know the values update slowly after a proper fix on the location has been established. As soon as your app is running rely on the `LocationListener` for location data.

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` is non-blocking. I don't mind even if it is blocked, since getting the accurate location is very crucial for my app. Is there anyway I can get the exact location at any cost as soon as the button is pressed?

Comment: No, getting a location fix will always take some time. You can't get around that. Just open Google Maps or some other maps or navigation app. They all have to initially establish a fix on the location. Depending on the location of the user and the device he is using that might take anywhere from one or two seconds up to 30 or more seconds.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51954/discussion-between-harikrishnan-t-and-xaver-kapeller)

Answer (score -2):

This is your total class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    private TextView latValueLabel,lonValueLabel ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        latValueLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latLabel);
        lonValueLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lonLabel);
        Button setButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set_button);
        setButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {             
                latValueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                lonValueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latValueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                lonValueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question... Read the question for once. This is not any more correct than your other answer. And please don't post multiple answers. Edit your old answer instead.